# Date in CocoaTouch

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4

I want to find the current date and the date that 10 days before from current date.I know how to find the current date.please anybody help me to find the date which 10 days before from current date..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NSDateComponents` to subtract the days from the current date.

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

NSDateComponents *sub_date = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[sub_date setDay:-10];

NSDate *tenDaysAgo = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:sub_date
                                                                   toDate:today
                                                                  options:0];

[sub_date release];
NSLog(@"Ten Days Ago: %@", tenDaysAgo);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dateWithTimeInterval:sinceDate:` to subtract 10 days from the current date.

Code example:

```
NSDate *todayDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *tenDaysAgoDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:-864000 sinceDate:todayDate];
```

The 864000 represents the seconds in ten days, the negative sets the calculation to days AGO, instead of forward.